# telegram bot. Forward message to another chat

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have a code simple telegram echo bot.

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

But I want to bot which will send the received message to another chat as Forward.
I tried following way

```
chat = '187458737'
bot.forward_message(chat, message.chat.id, message.text)
```

But It did not lead to success.
How I should modify my bot?

Answer (score 7):

you shoul do this :

```
bot.forward_message(to_chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
```

message_id- id of message wich you want to repost

Answer (score 0):

The `forwardMessage` doesn't have a parameter for the `text`. 
You need to pass the `chat_id` (target chat), the `from_chat_id` and the `message_id`

Comment: chatId = int('187458737')
bot.forward_message(chatId, chat.id, message.id) ?
Not working(( what did I miss?

Comment: You still need to use `message.chat.id`

Comment: bot.forward_message(chatId, message.chat.id, message.id) ?
Could you please write full line?

Comment: I don't use the python bot, but probably like this: `bot.forward_message(chatId, message.chat.id, message.message_id)`